# Input prompt is being displayed under program output on zyBooks. Is this my mistake?

Tags: python

Have I made a mistake here, or is this an error within zyBooks? It will not allow me to get full marks, as the input prompt is being displayed with the print statement in the program output, and it is specifically asking only for the print statement.

```
user_name = (input('What is your first name?'))
print('Hello', user_name, 'and welcome to CS Online!')
```

Here is the result, and then the result that it is expecting.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAyk2.png (The result)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb2Gw.png (The expected result)

Comment: The output looks normal both in IDLE and PyCharm. I feel this is only a zyBooks problem, and I'll be upset if I can't get a full mark because of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)'s `prompt` parameter is printed to stdout. So simply remove it.

```
user_name = input()
```

Comment: It does work, but I didn't think to try it without a prompt, as I thought that would be doing less than was asked of me. However, I will go ahead with it.